Bounding the norm of the solution to a particular system of abstract linear equations
This is my very first question :) I have been working on this problem for the past couple of days, and I find myself really stuck.
The problem goes as follows: let $V$ and $W$ be real Hilbert spaces, $A \in B(V, V)$, and $B \in B(W, V)$, where $B(W,V)$ denotes the space of linear and bounded operators between $W$ and $V$, and similarly $B(V,V)$. Let $B^* \in B(V, W)$ be the Hilbert adjoint of $B$. Assume that $B^*$ maps $V$ onto $W$, that $A$ is self-adjoint and that there are constants $\alpha>0$ and $\gamma>0$ for which
$$
\begin{aligned}
& (A v, v)_V \geq \alpha\|v\|_V^2, \quad \forall v \in N\left(B^*\right)=\operatorname{ker}\left(B^*\right), \\
& \sup _{v \in V} \frac{\left(B^* v, w\right)_W}{\|v\|_V} \geq \gamma\|w\|_W, \quad \forall w \in W .
\end{aligned}
$$
Assume also that the following problem has a solution: Find $u \in V$ and $p \in W$ such that
$$
\begin{aligned}
A u+B p & =f \in V \\
B^* u & =g \in W
\end{aligned}
$$
I need to bound $\|u\|_V$, where the bound (clearly) cannot depend on $u$ or $p$.
This is part of a longer problem, so it might help to know that I was able to show
$$
\|p\|_W \leq \frac{1}{\gamma}\left\{\|f\|_V+\|A\|\|u\|_V\right\}
$$
and that the solution $(u,p)$ is unique.
I have tried very hard to find a similar question on this website, but I could not. Sorry if this is a duplicate, please redirect me if so.
The most (relatively) promising approaches I have tried are the following:

The first inequality looks to be the relevant one, as $u \in V$. So if one could show that some transformation of $u$ is in the kernel of $B^*$, that might help. $u$ does not work, as $B^*u = g$. I tried $u - Bg$, and I would like to show $B^* ( u - Bg) = 0$. Using the second inequality gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
\gamma \| B^* ( u - Bg) \| & \leq \sup_{v \in V} \frac{\langle B^*v, B^*u - B^*Bg  \rangle}{\| v \|} \\
& = \frac{\langle v, Bg \rangle - \langle v, BB^*Bg \rangle}{\|v\|}
\end{aligned}
$$
I would like to conclude that this is $0$, but I don't know how, nor whether it's actually true. From there one could maybe use the first inequality and the inequality $\|u - Bg\| \geq |\|u\| - \|Bg\||$. Then maybe the fact that $u$ is a solution would give a simplification, though this does not look immediate to me.

I have tried to argue that $B^*$ is injective, which would give a very quick solution through $u = (B^*)^{-1} g$. But I could not, and I have a feeling that this is not true :) However, I have been able to show that $B$ is injective, assuming $B(x-y)=0$ and using the second inequality on $x-y$ and the definition of adjoint.


I am sorry if these details are irrelevant. Any hint would be appreciated :)
P.S. The title mention bounding the norm of the solution, which I think is correct, as $\| p\|$ is bounded by a function of $\|u\|$, so if we can bound the latter, we get a bound on the whole solution.

If I understand you correclty, you proved that the bounded operator
$$
T := \pmatrix{ A & B \\ B^* & 0}
$$
is bijective. By the open mapping theorem, its inverse is bounded, which should be the claim.

The OP wrote Assume that the following problem has a solution... -- it is not clear if he means that there is a solution for all right hand sides $f$ and $g$. If he means this, one can indeed use the open mapping theorem to find solutions with bounds depending on $f,g$.

Thank you, this is helpful, but as @Jochen said, the solution does not need to exist for all $f,g$, just for a given pair.

OK, I see. No idea how to prove the estimate. Maybe you can find a fitting reference by searching for saddle point problems, inf-sup condition, LBB condition.

Thank you for the hints, I'll try to look those up and post an answer if I can find one
